# how to make Advise loop for items in a DataTable and show realtime values on dataGridView

Tags: c#, ndde

I have a DataTable filled with data, there are columns called "ALIASNUM" and "VALUE".
I'm trying to get the values for all items in "ALIASNUM" column and put it in "VALUE" column.

this is my code:

```
NDde.Client.DdeClient client = new NDde.Client.DdeClient("TR1EMCodeEmulator", "Command");
client.Connect();
DataRow[] rowList = dataTable1.Select("ALIASNUM > 0 ");
foreach (DataRow dr in rowList)
{
     string alias = dr["ALIASNUM"].ToString();
     string currentValue = client.Request(alias, 60000);
     dr["VALUE"] = currentValue;
}
```

This code is working fine, but I want to use StartAdvise to make these values a realtime values and show the datatable on dataGridView with realtime values, how can I do this?

---

this is the full code after using startadvise:

1- handler for advise

```
private void client1_Advise(Object sender, NDde.Client.DdeAdviseEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow[] rowList1 = dataTable1.Select("ALIASNUM = " + e.Item);
    if (rowList1.Length > 0)
    {
        rowList1[0]["VALUE"] = e.Text;
    }
}
```

2- DDE Connection

```
string ddeApplication1 = "";
string ddeTopic1 = "";
ddeApplication1 = "TR1EMCodeEmulator";
ddeTopic1 = "Command";
NDde.Client.DdeClient client1 = new NDde.Client.DdeClient(ddeApplication1, ddeTopic1);
client1.Connect();
```

3- StartAdvise

```
//Get the values for the requested data through the DDE connections.
client1.Advise += client1_Advise;
DataRow[] rowList1 = dataTable1.Select("ALIASNUM > 0 ");
foreach (DataRow dr1 in rowList1)
    {
        string alias = dr1["ALIASNUM"].ToString();
        client1.StartAdvise(alias, 1, true, 60000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your setup method re-worked:

```
try
{
    NDde.Client.DdeClient client = new NDde.Client.DdeClient("TR1EMCodeEmulator", "Command");
    client.Connect();
    client.Advise += client_Advise;
    DataRow[] rowList = dataTable1.Select("ALIASNUM > 0 ");
    foreach (DataRow dr in rowList)
          client.StartAdvise(dr["ALIASNUM"] as String, 0, true, 60000);  //the zero is DDE type, replace as necessary
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Do what you need to here...
}
```

And here's a handler for advise:

```
private void client_Advise(Object sender, NDde.Client.DdeAdviseEventArgs e)
{
    //Tests to consider:  Is it the right format?  Is it valid?  What's the state?

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  //replace with whatever data you *really are updating*
    DataRow[] row = dt.Select("ALIASNUM = " + e.Item);
    if (row.Length > 0)
        row[0]["VALUE"] = e.Text;  //could use e.Data and convert from Byte[] to what you need (what is VALUE type?)
}
```

Other considerations:

1) If dataTable1 is derived through SQL calls, it *will* be slow.

2) You'll be at the mercy of grid refresh, so handle that where needed.

3) Always think about types.  DDE is sending type information and raw Bytes...use it where you can.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this code is working fine, but it only gets the value for the first item only whenever its value has changed, and it never gets the value for the next items, I appreciate if you can continue helping me, I really can't understand why this is happening and I can't find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: Expand on that for me.  Do you mean you only get a single value for each DDE Topic/Item?  Or that you only get a value for the first Topic/Item, and no more for it or any other link?  And what do you mean about the value changing?  Do you continue to get new values as changes occur?  If so, for which links?

Comment: It would also help if I knew more about what you are pulling from (i.e. what is your DDE server?).  What is "ALIASNUM"?  Since it appears to be a number, I'm wondering about what/how you are connecting to the DDE server?  Perhaps the link definition is the real underlying issue.  DDE links should be defined by Server, Topic, Item...is it correct to assume that Server="TR1EMCodeEmulator", Topic="Command", and Item=[ALIASNUM]?

Comment: yes, the DDE parameters are: Application="TR1EMCodeEmulator", Topic="Command" and Item=[ALIASNUM].
I'm actually using that DDE connection to communicate with a PLC, what I need to pull from DDE are the values of all Items (alias numbers), I was using the DDE Request to get these values and it was successful.

Comment: but now I need these values to be in real time, it means whenever a value has changed in the PLC for any Item (alias number), I want to get the new value automatically and update my datatable automatically, then at the end, I want to have my datagrid show all values for all items in real time.
After adding your code, I could see the value is updating automatically on the datagrid whenever this value has changed in the PLC, but it's actually happening only for the first item in my datatable and only if I have 2 items only in my datatable.

Comment: When I have 3 items in my datatable, I get the value updating for the first and third items only and I never get the value for the second item.
When I have 4 items in my datatable, I get the value updating for the first and third and 4th items only and I never get the value for the second item.
When I have all items (856 items), sometimes I get this error "Min (802) must be less than or equal to max (-1) in a Range object.", the number 802 is different every time I run the application.

Comment: I have added the main code lines in my question for your reference.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you already noticed the type issue; you're using 1, which is good (that's CF_TEXT).  Here's a link to the full list, if you're curious:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx.  In regard to the "Range" error...I believe it's possible that the value you are requesting is defined as just that in the PLC.  I've never tried to request DDE for such a thing, so I don't have good advice there.

Comment: Are you certain that all of your ALIASNUM values are unique?  I.e. do the first and second records have the same ALIASNUM?